# TypeError when using Django update_or_create

Tags: django, orm

I try to use update_or_create method but got a TypeError

Django 2.2.5
Python 3.7

> TypeError: update_or_create() got multiple values for keyword argument
> 'dcf_ide'

I probably misunderstand how to use update_or_create method
I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915911/django-update-or-create-gets-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint)

**datas in DataCorrectionForm model before update**

```
         dcf_ide     pat      status                       crated_date
0   43_inc_poi_1  01-001           1  2022-10-04 08:36:21.991740+00:00
1   43_inc_poi_3  01-003           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.031926+00:00
2   43_inc_poi_7  02-001           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.054673+00:00
3   43_inc_poi_9  01-050           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.075715+00:00
4  43_inc_poi_11  01-002           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.096237+00:00
5   46_inc_tai_2  02-002           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.147911+00:00
6   46_inc_tai_4  01-004           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.175169+00:00
7   46_inc_tai_7  02-001           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.193514+00:00
8   46_inc_tai_9  01-050           1  2022-10-04 08:36:22.210608+00:00
```

```
records = DCF_AFTER_UPDATE.to_dict(orient='records')
for record in records:
    DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(
         dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide'],
         **record
    )
```

**Update/Create**

```
         dcf_ide     pat      status                       crated_date
0   43_inc_poi_1  01-001           0  2022-10-04 08:36:21.991740+00:00    #<= update status column
1   43_inc_poi_3  01-003           2  2022-10-04 08:36:22.031926+00:00    #<= update status column
2   43_inc_poi_7  02-001           2  2022-10-04 08:36:22.054673+00:00    #<= update status column
3   43_inc_poi_9  01-050           2  2022-10-04 08:36:22.075715+00:00    #<= update status column
4  43_inc_poi_11  01-002           2  2022-10-04 08:36:22.096237+00:00    #<= update status column
5   46_inc_tai_2  02-002           2  2022-10-04 08:36:22.147911+00:00    #<= update status column
6   46_inc_tai_4  01-004           2  2022-10-04 08:36:22.175169+00:00    #<= update status column
7   46_inc_tai_7  02-001           0  2022-10-04 08:36:22.193514+00:00    #<= update status column
8   46_inc_tai_9  01-050           2  2022-10-04 08:36:22.210608+00:00    #<= update status column
1   43_inc_poi_2  02-002           1  2022-10-04 10:00:02.896153+00:00    #<= create row
0   46_inc_tai_1  01-001           1  2022-10-04 10:00:10.937815+00:00    #<= create row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915911/django-update-or-create-gets-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint) you shared I notice a difference, you define your code like:

```
DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(
     dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide'],
     **record
)
```

Where you use the `**kwargs` notation for the `**record`.

In the post they define the `update_or_create` as:

```
Model.objects.update_or_create(field1=val1,
                               field2=val2,
                               defaults={
                                   'field3': val3,
                                   'field4': val4
                               })
```

You can see the difference with the `defaults={'field3': val3,'field4': val4})`

I suppose you should follow this example to make it work and write your code like this:

```
DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(
         dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide'],
         defaults=record
    )
```

Please note I've not ran this code myself, I just looked at the example you shared.

Answer (score 1):

When you do: `update_or_create(dcfe_ide=record['dcf_ide'], **record)` you are adding the entire `record` dictionary as argument.

if your `record` variable is something like: `{'dcf_ide': '...', 'other': '...'}`, you are actually doing:

```py
DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(
    dcf_ide='...',
    dcf_ide='...',
    other: '...',
)
```

You cannot pass the same keyword argument twice to a function.
In fact, with what you provided us, the `dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide']` argument does not have any sense since you then pass the entire `record` dict as kwargs.

Doing `DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(**record)` is enough.

Comment: ```DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(**record)``` give me IntegretyError ``` django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERREUR:  la valeur d'une clé dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « datas_dcf_ide_key »```

Comment: @DigitalDirk: doing ```   DataCorrectionForm.objects.update_or_create(
                dcf_ide=record['dcf_ide'],
                defaults = {
                    'category':record['category'],
                    'crf':record['crf'],
                    ...
                }
            )``` works